# Where/how can I install TypeScript 1.1?

Tags: typescript

I need TypeScript 1.1 as our project is using that version. Where can I get it and how do I install it?

Also, I installed TypeScript 1.4, do I need to uninstall it?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend you update to 1.4.

> do I need to uninstall it

No they can coexist.

For VS2013 : https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/37f81de4-35dd-47de-8ae9-795112dcfc75

For others see the blog post : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/10/06/announcing-typescript-1-1-ctp.aspx

Comment: I recommend 1.4 too. Unfortunately it's not my call. Thanks

Comment: Moving the build out of MSBuild (to something like grunt/gulp/something else) will make it easier for you to keep using older versions when Visual studio updates.